# How can I make Ubuntu dock windows like Windows 7?

Tags: windows, ubuntu

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to use Window snapping for Ubuntu?](https://superuser.com/questions/245475/how-to-use-window-snapping-for-ubuntu)

I'm learning Ubuntu and I am missing the Windows 7 docking. Windows key + arrow key will dock the window. How can I replicate this feature for Ubuntu?